# How do I align views at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-layout

Here's my layout code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>

            <Button android:text="@string/label_submit_button"
                android:id="@+id/Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What this looks like is on the left and what I want it to look like is on the right.

[image: Android Layout - Actual (Left) and Desired (Right)]

The obvious answer is to set the TextView to fill_parent on height, but this causes no room to be left for the button or entry field.

Essentially the issue is that I want the submit button and the text entry to be a fixed height at the bottom and the text view to fill the rest of the space. Similarly, in the horizontal linear layout I want the submit button to wrap its content and for the text entry to fill the rest of the space.

If the first item in a linear layout is told to fill_parent it does exactly that, leaving no room for other items. How do I get an item which is first in a linear layout to fill all space apart from the minimum required by the rest of the items in the layout?

---

Relative layouts were indeed the answer:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:text="@string/label_submit_button"
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @oneself Paint ;) I'm using a skin on the emulator though courtesy of Tea Vui Huang http://teavuihuang.com/android/

Comment: +1 for posting the layout XML that solved it. Helped me figure out what was wrong with mine.

Answer (score 547, accepted):

The modern way to do this is to have a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) and constrain the bottom of the view to the bottom of the ConstraintLayout with **`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`**

The example below creates a FloatingActionButton that will be aligned to the end and the bottom of the screen.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For reference, I will keep my old answer.

Before the introduction of ConstraintLayout the answer was a [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

---

If you have a relative layout that fills the whole screen you should be able to use [`android:layout_alignParentBottom`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentBottom) to move the button to the bottom of the screen.

If your views at the bottom are not shown in a relative layout then maybe the layout above it takes all the space. In this case you can put the view, that should be at the bottom, first in your layout file and position the rest of the layout above the views with `android:layout_above`. This enables the bottom view to take as much space as it needs, and the rest of the layout can fill all the rest of the screen.

Comment: FYI: that wouldn't work inside a ScrollView.  This is the issue I am facing now.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126347/android-relativelayout-how-to-alignparentbottom-when-wrapped-in-a-scrollview

Comment: That is correct ScrollViews and Relative Layouts do not mix very well. If you have to much content to display everything on one page just use a linearlayout and put in the bottom view last. If you want the view to appear last in the scrollview on small screens and at the bottom of the page on bigger phones consider using different layout files and uses ressource qualifiers to let the device choose the correct layout file.

Comment: ok.. what's the point of the second paragraph of the answer here? "You should find a layout which covers the bottom of the screen first"?  then we should use layout_alignParentBottom inside the layout? What do we need `android:layout_above` for?

Comment: You need the above if you want to something like a bar at the bottom and then a LinearLayout above this bar that stretches from the top of the screen to the bar.

Comment: I have read in one of "Android Weekly" `that RelativeLayout` is memory consuming and should be avoided whenever it is possible.

Comment: Relative layout is the best option for such scenario

Comment: That properties about botton aligment are not available for my solution:

No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' in package 'com.XXX' XXX C:\projects\erp\XXX\Resources\layout\layout_test.axml

Comment: Tried this and it killed the designer

Answer (score 164):

In a `ScrollView` this doesn't work, as the `RelativeLayout` would then overlap whatever is in the `ScrollView` at the bottom of the page.

I fixed it using a dynamically stretching `FrameLayout` :

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- content goes here -->

                <!-- stretching frame layout, using layout_weight -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

                <!-- content fixated to the bottom of the screen -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
                                   <!-- your bottom content -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this is great - also, it's "minimal invasive", and more intuitive than the RelativeLayout approach. I'd give more than one upvote if I could!

Comment: I use your solution in my application, but in my case I want that when keyboard appears, the buttons stay at the bottom of the screen (behind the keyboard) There is a sulution for that ? Thaks.

Comment: @DoubleYo: in the manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: IF you want the bottom to be fixed permanently so that is shows all the time this does not work. Otherwise it works.

Answer (score 75):

You can keep your initial linear layout by nesting the relative layout within the linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:text="welcome" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:text="submit" 
            android:id="@+id/Button" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </Button>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is a messy approach in that it's not very modular. You shouldn't have overlapping layouts. This design won't work as soon as you want to change the background of the RelativeLayout or want to make any of the views bigger or add views.

Answer (score 46):

The answer above (by Janusz) is quite correct, but I personnally don't feel 100% confortable with RelativeLayouts, so I prefer to introduce a 'filler', empty TextView, like this:

```
<!-- filler -->
<TextView android:layout_height="0dip" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" />
```

before the element that should be at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Is this gonna expand to x or y axis. Giving 0dip for height will make the textview without any height ? or will expand as much as it can just like to x axis ?

Comment: This expands vertically because the height (vertical axis) is set to 0 and the weight to 1 (assuming that other elements have a zero weight).

Comment: On the x axis, it will be as its parent (fill_parent)

Comment: Rather than a textview I would use another linear layout. Layout view seems to imply it can be used to fill space?

Answer (score 41):

You can do this with a LinearLayout or a ScrollView, too. Sometimes it is easier to implement than a RelativeLayout. The only thing you need to do is to add the following view **before** the Views you want to align to the bottom of the screen:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This creates an empty view, filling the empty space and pushing the next views to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: this concept is similar to the filler as @Timores said earlier.

Comment: That's it what I am looking for since hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

#### 1. Use `ConstraintLayout` in your root Layout

And set `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to let the Layout on the bottom of the screen:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

#### 2. Use `FrameLayout` in your root Layout

Just set `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` in your layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

#### 3. Use `LinearLayout` in your root Layout (`android:orientation="vertical"`)

**(1) Set a layout `android:layout_weight="1"` on the top of the your Layout**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="welcome" />
```

**(2) Set the child `LinearLayout` for `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="bottom"`**

The main attribute is `ndroid:gravity="bottom"`, let the child View on the bottom of Layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

#### 4. Use `RelativeLayout` in the root Layout

And set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to let the Layout on the bottom of the screen

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 29):

This also works.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 

    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 


    />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: gravity="bottom" to float LinearLayout elements to bottom]

Comment: android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
has no effect unless the LinearLayout is nested inside a RelativeLayout.

Comment: An explanation would be in order (e.g. the essential change, how it works, why it works, etc.).

Answer (score 24):

Following up on [Timores's elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-do-i-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/5694449#5694449), I have found that the following creates a vertical fill in a vertical LinearLayout and a horizontal fill in a horizontal LinearLayout:

```
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: @sepehr There must be another factor at play in the case you found where my solution doesn't work. I just tried my solution in a fragment layout, and it works there as well.

Comment: weights are supported in linear layouts and @sepehr they will work in fragments, activities, notifications, dialogs as well ;)

Comment: This works! What a simple solution.

Answer (score 20):

You don't even need to nest the second `relative` layout inside the first one. Simply use the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the *Button* and *EditText*.

Comment: Just a note that although this works with the Button and EditText, if you tried to align a TableLayout this way it would not work. You would have to nest it inside of another RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't wish to make many changes, then you could just put:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for the TextView having ID as `@+id/TextView` i.e

```
<TextView android:text="@string/welcome" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Or add a surrounding LinearLayout with android:layout_weight="1" - this also works well inside a ScrollView!

Answer (score 11):

Creating both *header* and *footer*, here is an example:

#### Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#FF0000">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FFFF00">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For a case like this, always use RelativeLayouts. A LinearLayout is not intended for such a usage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Place your layout here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the below code. Align the button to buttom. It's working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Payment Page" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`  in your `<RelativeLayout>`.

This will definitely help.

Comment: That presumes the user wants to use a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a linear layout too.

Just provide Height = 0dp and weight = 1 to the layout above and the one you want in the bottom. Just write height = wrap content and no weight.

It provides wrap content for the layout (the one that contains your edit text and button) and then the one that has weight occupies the rest of the layout.

I discovered this by accident.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a hierarchy like this:

```
<ScrollView> 
  |-- <RelativeLayout> 
    |-- <LinearLayout>
```

First, apply `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView` and then apply `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the `LinearLayout`.

This worked for me perfectly.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHorizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just give your top child view (the TextView **@+id/TextView**) an attribute:
 `android:layout_weight="1"`.

This will force all other elements below it to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution Janusz posted, but I added padding to the last View since the top part of my layout was a ScrollView.

The ScrollView will be partly hidden as it grows with content. Using `android:paddingBottom` on the last View helps show all the content in the ScrollView.