# Android RelativeLayout : how to alignParentBottom when wrapped in a ScrollView?

Tags: android

The problem I am having seems to be that if I have a view (e.g. myButton) inside a RelativeLayout set to alignParentBottom - (as per the code below) - and then wrap the RelativeLayout with a scrollview (necessary so the content will be viewable on smaller screens or when orientation changes to landscape) - then, when the parent bottom is NOT visible (for example when changed to landscape orientation) myButton is displayed at the TOP of the page - NOT the bottom.

How can you align a view to the bottom of the screen and have it remain at the bottom even if the bottom is below the scroll?

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillViewport="true">



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/topLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">



... lots of views and stuff


<Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:id="@+id/myButton"  
android:text="Click Me" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: do you know how to do this today?

Answer (score 28):

Take the button out of the SCrollview, Wrap both the Scrollview and the Button in a Linear Layout, set the scrollview's height to 0dip and set it's weight to 1, do not set any weight property for the button, so the scrollview can occupy all the remaining space saving only the button's space way at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        ....lots of views...


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But this would make the `Button` always remain at the bottom of the screen even when the `ScrollView` is scrollable, right?

Comment: This's a solution I like, but just beware of that "weight" is bad for performance

Comment: Good answer, now explain _why_ a `layout_height` of `0` and a `layout_weight` of `1` is effective for producing the desired effect.

Answer (score 7):

Using fill_parent as the height of a child of a ScrollView is meaningless. You are telling the RelativeLayout to be always as tall as its parent. In this case, the ScrollView becomes useless! The height of the RelativeLayout should be set to wrap_content, in which case, depending on what the RelativeLayout contains, alignParentBottom may not work as you expect. You should simply use a LinearLayout, it will be much much simpler.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why you say the scrollview becomes useless, its function is to allow scrolling, and it does that...so I have to use it. I have to use RelativeLayout so that I can use android_alignParentBottom. I don't see how using LinearLayout would solve this because then I can't align myButton to the bottom of the screen. Is it just not possible to align a view to the bottom of the screen and support scrolling at the same time?

Comment: It's useless if the child has height=fill_parent. fill_parent means "I want to be as tall as my parent." So if the content of the ScrollView is as big as the ScrollView itself, it won't scroll.

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your guidance. However, the layout does indeed scroll, that is not the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I am explaining why your layout doesn't work like you expect, because it can't by using fill_parent.

Comment: Hi Romain, I'm in a similar situation (except I'm sort of bound to a RelativeLayout by some code i can't edit). the RelativeLayout is set to wrap_content and the layout for my button is set to alignParentBottom, but as the OP says, the button appears at the TOP of the relativelayout. Is there something that is trying to ensure all elements of the relativelayout are always visible?

Comment: A common scenario I've encountered this for is when I want a view scrollable when the soft keyboard is open (e.g. login screen - I want the user to be able to scroll to the login button without having to close the keyboard). Is there a more accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

well you could try this out

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fillViewport="true">



        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/topLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">



            ... lots of views and stuff


            <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:text="Click Me" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you buddy! I faced same problem and started thinking it's impossible. Your solution helps me a lot

Answer (score 3):

None of these solutions were satisfying for me, so I'll post my own solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- lots of stuff -->

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Little explanation: when there is a lot of space (f.e. in portrait) Space view will fill that space and push Button down. When there is no space (f.e. in landscape) Space view will have 0 height and Button will be directly below content.

Comment: Yess adding this line to RelativeLayout will help. `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: Just stumbled upon this, is there any advantage in using the <Space> ?
You could just add gravity=bottom and height=0dp and weight=1  directly to the button and if has the same effect, hasnt it?

Answer (score -1):

It's a little bit late, but the simpliest solution is to add

```
android:below="@id/lots_of_stuffs"
```

Like this:

```
<ScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

   <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/topLayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">


     <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/lots_of_stuffs" >

       ... lots of views and stuff

     </LinearLayout>

    <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
      android:id="@+id/myButton"  
      android:text="Click Me"
      android:below="@id/lots_of_stuffs" /> <!-- Here is the "hack" -->

   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: bit late and still not a proper solution, this will stretch button to its fill height.