# Android: How to align ads to the bottom of screen even if the view scrolls?

Tags: android

I previously asked a question that I still have not been able to solve:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126347/android-relativelayout-how-to-alignparentbottom-when-wrapped-in-a-scrollview
```

What I am trying to do is align a view to the bottom of the screen, using either a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, and then wrap that layout in a scrollview to permit scrolling when necessary (for changes to landscape orientation or on small screen devices).

To date, what I find is that anything aligned to parent bottom works great as long at the bottom is visible...but if the bottom is below the scroll, the view that is aligned parent bottom jumps up to the top.

This seems like a very common design for ads that appear on the bottom, so I would think that this is possible. Is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if there is ONE method to do that, but here is a trick I use to do this kind of stuff. If this is what you want :
[alt text http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/3419/scrollviewandads.png](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/3419/scrollviewandads.png)
Here is my code for it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollAds">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvInScroll" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae metus ac leo ultrices placerat. Curabitur vel ipsum vitae urna ultricies rhoncus. Proin tempus felis nec turpis feugiat vitae vestibulum arcu faucibus. Donec dapibus mi at nisl mattis a malesuada lectus feugiat. Etiam ultricies adipiscing nisi, sed scelerisque mauris ultricies sagittis. Proin blandit dignissim magna, id consectetur justo molestie in. Nullam id nunc et sem dictum malesuada ac et libero. Integer vitae mattis est. Nulla sodales dolor nec metus tempor a vestibulum nisl pellentesque. Suspendisse interdum, risus non pulvinar aliquet, tellus elit sodales ligula, vitae mollis nisi massa eget purus. Etiam pharetra consectetur ipsum, eu pretium est egestas eu. Vivamus varius tortor ac leo gravida tempus. Ut semper scelerisque vestibulum. Morbi pretium neque vel neque tempus tempus. Proin tellus tortor, posuere nec dignissim in, venenatis hendrerit augue. Etiam eget justo a nisl semper lobortis. Etiam cursus sodales ipsum non sagittis. Vivamus non metus augue, vehicula iaculis tortor. Aenean tristique orci id lorem consequat vitae commodo metus auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae metus ac leo ultrices placerat. Curabitur vel ipsum vitae urna ultricies rhoncus. Proin tempus felis nec turpis feugiat vitae vestibulum arcu faucibus. Donec dapibus mi at nisl mattis a malesuada lectus feugiat. Etiam ultricies adipiscing nisi, sed scelerisque mauris ultricies sagittis. Proin blandit dignissim magna, id consectetur justo molestie in. Nullam id nunc et sem dictum malesuada ac et libero. Integer vitae mattis est. Nulla sodales dolor nec metus tempor a vestibulum nisl pellentesque. Suspendisse interdum, risus non pulvinar aliquet, tellus elit sodales ligula, vitae mollis nisi massa eget purus. Etiam pharetra consectetur ipsum, eu pretium est egestas eu. Vivamus varius tortor ac leo gravida tempus. Ut semper scelerisque vestibulum. Morbi pretium neque vel neque tempus tempus. Proin tellus tortor, posuere nec dignissim in, venenatis hendrerit augue. Etiam eget justo a nisl semper lobortis. Etiam cursus sodales ipsum non sagittis. Vivamus non metus augue, vehicula iaculis tortor. Aenean tristique orci id lorem consequat vitae commodo metus auctor. "></TextView>
</ScrollView>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tvBelowScroll"
    android:text="This is your ads TV" android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="18dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this matches your hopes ;) It just a trick with margins.

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfect. I needed a fresh way of looking at it and the outside RelativeLayout was the answer. Much obliged!