# how to Place an AdMob ad at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

iam trying to place admob add at bnottom of my application ...for that i wrote the following code ....am getting entire application except adds...can u please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/wp" 
android:gravity="right" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@color/black" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/header" 
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:textColor="@color/white" 
            android:text="Tip Calculator" 
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:textSize="26sp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:id="@+id/TextView07"></TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


<AbsoluteLayout

android:id="@+id/widget0"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/widget28"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="17px"

android:text="Amount of Bill          $"

android:layout_x="40px"

android:layout_y="48px"

android:textColor="@color/white"

>

</TextView>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/widget29"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text="Percentage to Tip"

android:textColor="@color/white"

android:layout_x="40px"

android:layout_y="98px"

>

</TextView>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/widget30"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text="Number of People"

android:textColor="@color/white"

android:layout_x="40px"

android:layout_y="148px"

>

</TextView>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/widget31"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="18px"

android:text="Tip Amout                 $"

android:textColor="@color/white"

android:layout_x="40px"

android:layout_y="262px"



>

</TextView>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/widget32"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="18px"

android:text="Total Per Person       $"

android:textColor="@color/white"

android:layout_x="40px"

android:layout_y="302px"

>

</TextView>

<Button

android:id="@+id/btncalculate"

android:layout_width="87px"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text="Calculate"

android:textColor="@color/black"

android:layout_x="40px"

android:layout_y="198px"

>

</Button>

<Button

android:id="@+id/btnreset"

android:layout_width="86px"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text="Reset"

android:textColor="@color/black"

android:layout_x="140px"

android:layout_y="198px"

>

</Button>

<EditText

android:id="@+id/txtbillamount"

android:layout_width="99px"

android:layout_height="36px"

android:text=""

android:textSize="18sp"

android:layout_x="200px"

android:layout_y="38px"

>

</EditText>

<EditText

android:id="@+id/txtpercentage"

android:layout_width="51px"

android:layout_height="36px"

android:text=""

android:textSize="18sp"

android:layout_x="200px"

android:layout_y="88px"

>

</EditText>

<EditText

android:id="@+id/txtpeople"

android:layout_width="51px"

android:layout_height="36px"

android:text=""

android:textSize="18sp"

android:layout_x="200px"

android:layout_y="138px"

>

</EditText>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/txttipamount"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:text=""

android:textColor="@color/white"

android:layout_x="200px"

android:layout_y="262px"

>

</TextView>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/txtperperson"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="99px"

android:text=""

android:textColor="@color/white"

android:layout_x="200px"

android:layout_y="302px"

>

</TextView>

<TextView 

android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

android:text="%" android:textColor="@color/white" 

android:id="@+id/percentageview" 

android:layout_x="265dip"

 android:layout_y="92dip">

 </TextView>

</AbsoluteLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
<Button android:id="@+id/btnGetMoreResults"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
 android:text="Get more"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use your AdMob Design Parameters in place of Button code here.

Comment: This problem is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473472/android-how-to-align-ads-to-the-bottom-of-screen-even-if-the-view-scrolls)..You will get your answer

Answer (score 4):

1. use below on your remaining elements except admob.

   ```
   layout_weight="1.0"
   layout_height="0dp"
   ```
2. use below on your admob wrapper layout

   ```
   android:gravity="bottom"
   ```

For example,

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#000000">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">
           // here is remaining elements
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom">
           // admob element here
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and insert admob by code,

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adView.setLayoutParams(params);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Answer (score -1):

This blog post will certainly help you:

http://www.ahotbrew.com/how-to-put-admob-banner-on-the-bottom

The important part here are android:layout_alignParentBottom=”true” for the AdView and android:layout_alignParentTop=”true” for the LinearLayout afterwards.