# align a text view below a scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the following layout hierarchy:
LinearLayout
....LinearLayout
.......      TextView
....RelativeLayout
..........TextView
....ScrollView
....Place where I want the fixed bottom text view

I read on SO - where I needed to enter the following attribute to ScrollView:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This ensured that my bottom text view ( intended to be fixed ) was shown.

So while this works - the problem is - if I have less content in my scroll view ( content would be populated dynamically ) - the bottom text view climbs up leaving making it look real ugly.

What I want is to have the bottom view fixed - irrrespective of the content of the scroll view.

here is my layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout style="@style/ExamTitleBar" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgPrevious"
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:onClick="previous"
            android:src="@drawable/previous" />

         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgHome"
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home" />

        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />

        <TextView style="@style/ExamTitleBarText" />

        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgNext"
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_search"
            android:onClick="next"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgReport"
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_search"
            android:onClick="reportDisplay"
            android:src="@drawable/setttings" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout style="@style/MessageBar" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msgBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionCount"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>


     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questionlabel"
         android:layout_weight="1">


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:fontFamily="Helvetica"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>



        <LinearLayout style="@style/SeparatorBarTop" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/separatorBar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>



        <RadioGroup 
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
             android:fontFamily="Helvetica"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            >

            <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButtons"
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Option1" />

            <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButtons"
                android:id="@+id/option2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Option2" />

            <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButtons"
                android:id="@+id/option3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Option3" 
                />

            <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButtons"
                android:id="@+id/option4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Option4" />
        </RadioGroup>



        <LinearLayout style="@style/SeparatorBarBottom" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/separatorBar2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- image view goes here start -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/velocity_graph" />
        <!-- image view goes here end -->

        <TextView style="@style/AnswerDetails"
            android:id="@+id/AnswerDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip" 
            android:fontFamily="Helvetica"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>



        <!-- separator bar for image start
        <LinearLayout style="@style/SeparatorBarBottom" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/separatorImageBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        separator for for image end -->

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- desired fixed bottom view -->
    <LinearLayout  android:layout_gravity="bottom" style="@style/ExamTitleBar" >
        <TextView style="@style/ExamTitleBarText" />
    </LinearLayout>
     <!-- moiraine end -->





</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ScrollView height to a fixed size. eg. `android:layout_height="240dp"`. One RelativeLayout with all the components will be enough, use alignBottom. Nesting layouts slows down your app performance see dev docs:http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)

Comment: Thanks Michael - however I read on SO that mixing relativelayouts with scroll views seem to give problems - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126347/android-relativelayout-how-to-alignparentbottom-when-wrapped-in-a-scrollview - is that not true ?

Answer (score 0):

1.The last `Linearlayout` should have a fixed height;

2.So many style, plz put layout attr in layout ;

3.`RelativeLayout` is better in this condition;

4.When `android:orientation="vertical"`,`android:layout_gravity="bottom"` is useless

Comment: Thanks - #1 giving the last linear layout a fixed height still moves the layout in the middle at times  and thanks #4 I removed the layout_gravity .About #3 using a Relative Layout - I read somewhere that scroll views and relative layouts dont work well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126347/android-relativelayout-how-to-alignparentbottom-when-wrapped-in-a-scrollview

Comment: Try write style inline; Show me the complete code;#3 it say RelativeLayout in Scrollview ,  we need Scrollview in RelativeLayout