# ScrollView with alignparentbottom element

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i want to achieve layout which looks like this

[image: make offer layout]

in which above content is scrollable and 'Make offer' button would be at the bottom of screen. But whenever user starts typing it should appear above keyboard so that it would be easy to click.
i have went through similar ans like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23215713/3746306). but those solutions arent working in my case. adding [screencast](http://www.screencast.com/t/Ce6m9Y2f) as well to show current behavior of layout.

current xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_48dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/padding_4dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/insidecardone"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/constant_value"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                                android:text="Charge per day"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />


                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/tvRentPerday"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:hint="Rs.        "
                                android:gravity="center"

                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:maxLength="4"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/insidecardtwo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/insidecardone"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/con_duration"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                                android:text="Duration (Days)"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/num_days"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_24dp"
                                android:text="10"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16"

                                />




                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                            android:id="@+id/third_relative"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/insidecardtwo">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/negotiable_text"

                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16"
                                android:text="Negotiable"/>

                            <Switch
                                android:id="@+id/negotiable"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:showText="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/third_relative"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                            android:background="@color/grey_lighter" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/third_relative"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_24dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/total_constant"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Total Amount"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvAmount"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"

                                android:textColor="#ff4f00"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/total_constant_mutterfly"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/total_constant"
                                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                                android:text="@string/process_fee_text"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                                android:textSize="8sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/middlecard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/firstcard"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/padding_4dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/middlecard_relative"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/deposite"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Deposit"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/knowmore"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/deposite"
                                android:text="@string/txt_know_more"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_extra_small_10"
                                />


                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/middletwo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/middlecard_relative"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/middle_con_duration"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:text="Charge (Rs.)"

                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/etDeposit"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:hint="1000"

                                android:maxLength="4"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16"

                                />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/seccard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/middlecard"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/padding_4dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/describe_constant_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                            android:text="Describe Your item"
                            android:textColor="#ff4f00"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rlTohide"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/greyborder_transparentbg"
                            >

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img1"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_width="40dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/addimg"
                                android:layout_height="40dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@id/img1"
                                android:text="(Optional)"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_extra_small_10"
                                android:textColor="@color/text_grey_opc"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                />


                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <ImageView
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:id="@+id/imgResource"
                            android:layout_width="120dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/insidecardone"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"

                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/con_product_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:text="Name Of Product"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/product_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/con_product_name"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/con_product_name"

                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:hint="E.g. Nikon DSLR"
                                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:maxLength="30"
                                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_16dp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/insidecardtwo"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_4dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_8dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/Description"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:text="Description :"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/desc_box"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/Description"
                                android:hint="E.g. Comes with 18-55 mm lens, charger and carry case"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/white_border_request_screen"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big_16" />

                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makeOffer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/padding_48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/new_primary_text"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_make_offr"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Basically what i have did is Relative layout as parent and used  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
parameter to align button at bottom and added rest of the content to ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

set your `ScrollView` above offer button and remove margin

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/makeOffer">
```

Change `windowSoftInputMode` of your activity in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: manifest part is already done.. trying with other modifications

Answer (score 0):

It only takes one parameter to work

```
 android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

Add this to `<ScrollView />`

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#isScrollContainer)

and only one tag in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```