# Android Text Input Special UI Item

Tags: android, user-interface, button, keyboard, android-edittext

I'm creating an IM client/server application for the Android OS, and am currently putting together the user interface. Right now, my interface consists of a `EditText` element, and a `Button` element. When I tap on the `EditText` element, a keyboard pops up and allows you to type.

What I would like to have is something like the text entry area and send button in the default Android SMS app. Something like this: 
[image]
The text input field and Send button would stay at the bottom of the screen, and when tapped on, the keyboard would push the text field and button up above it.

Is this possible using only `EditText` and `Button` elements?

Thank you for any suggestions or advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` for the activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

You can find details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my manifest file and it started to work. I also used the relative layout in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen if any one is interested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this possible using only EditText and Button elements?

Answer-This type of functionality is possible in any type of view

I give just short tutorial on your question 
Generally we use only linearlayout in xml file.But at view level android gives many more feature like Relative layout and much more.At this time we just discuss about the relative layout because it can solve your purpose.

In Relative layout it not use the ***android:orientation*** feature like linear layout it used another feature.In relative layout take some points in your mind...

1. we always give id to every view using android:id="@+id/GiveName"
2. for alignment of any view we used android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/givesname" same for
   right,above and below where **givesname=id of that view from which this view is    align**.

   Ex. is [gives example with screen shot](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)

   ***After this i give the sample xml file in which you get the above type of feature in your question***

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       android:id="@+id/llWriteCommentWall" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">
>       <Button android:id="@+id/btButtonComments"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
>         android:text="Comments" 
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
>       <EditText android:id="@+id/etEdittext"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:hint="Write a comment....   "
>         android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
>         android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btButtonComments" 
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
>     </RelativeLayout>
> ```

**ScreenShot of above example**

[image: At Simple Mode] [image: At Click on Edittext]

In this Example we used **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** - this attribute is the main reason for view like this,it always align any view in bottom even softkeyboard is shown.it contain boolean value,true gives always align bottom and false nothing.

the other relative attribute is **android:layout_alignParentRight="true",android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" ,android:layout_alignParentTop="true"**-all attribute give feature as written.

**Lastly you include this xml file at any java file through setContentView(xmlFileName)**