# How to prevent Title bar hiding when keyboard in active?

Tags: android

I have one form (Scroll View) in TabActivity, tabs appears on bottom of the page, and I have one EditText element bottom of the page. Whenever user wants to enter text total UI moving top along with Title bar. Is there any possibility to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) to the activity in your Manifest. Otherwise change the Layout to relative and make your EditText `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Refer this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5401828/598170)

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in android manifest with your activity or refer [SoftInputMode documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#softInputMode).