# how to set a button at a fixed location on the bottom of UI?

Tags: android

I want a button to appear at fixed location all the time, in the footer of the UI ؟ ( always, if it has components above it or not )

Comment: come on, paste the XML here (on gist.github.com if its too big) please

Comment: same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779688/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please take one Relative layout under your main layout . Set its height and width as fill parent and set its gravity as bottom and put any textview or any button you want in it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Bottom Gravity" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Without Gravity" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect Answer. Works. But should use "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent"

Comment: It works perfectly, but any clues if there is anyway to the button being not elevated by keyboard?

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked for me. I had the nesting of Linearlayout. One of them I changed to RelativeLayout with the attributes and values as you specified and It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the layout you are using.

On a RelativeLayout there is

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

On a LinearLayout, place it at the bottom and make sure to set the elements layout_weight properly.

Also, check the property

```
android:layout_gravity
```

and notice it's different than

```
android:gravity
```

Comment: i confirm your answer , he should use a relativeLayout to fixe the button at the bottom with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, and i want just to add that if he want to keep his button to the front , in his code he can call the method : `btn.bringToFront()`

Answer (score 2):

Set `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

in your relative layout.

Comment: This answer could be improved by paying attention to formatting.

Answer (score 1):

if any one have two button you can just make this it orks for me

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Valider"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Annuler"/>
     </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>`
```