# How to Set a Button at a fixed position even when respective Activity has ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Is there a way to use some non scrollable view when the activity has ScrollView component?

I want that my button behaves similar to the button in the question below, I want it fixed on the bottom of the UI too:

[how to set a button at a fixed location on the bottom of UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519345/how-to-set-a-button-at-a-fixed-location-on-the-bottom-of-ui)

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent ">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_frameview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep the button out of the ScrollView and position it at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you have attached in your question shows how you can do it. You can use `RelativeLayout` for this. The idea is, you need to tell a button to stay on bottom of the screen & tell the scrollview to stay above the Button along with it's scrollable content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnMy">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/btnMy"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_frameview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="20dp">
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```