# Which layout should I select?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am coming back to Android after a really long absence and it turns out, I've pretty much forgotten everything.

I want to a build a UI like this:

[image]

The buttons Item1 and Item2 trigger a move to another page, while the Perform Action button does an action in place.  And the ad should be docked to the bottom of the screen.

What layout should I pick to achieve this UI?
I am targeting Android 2.2 (if that matters).

Comment: @Dr.nik I tried Table layout, but it's impractical.

Comment: as per rahul please try with Relative layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe going for a Relative Layout helps. May be this can help, although you might want to reshuffle things a bit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:text="@string/item1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:text="@string/item2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/ad_goes_here" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:text="@string/perform_action" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 for exact catch, but please elaborate you answer with example as the himself mentions he forgets everything

Comment: @AngryHacker: I've inserted button at the place of that ad. You can always change it with the exact description that suits your ad.

Answer (score 3):

```
I think using Linear Layout is best


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
 android:id="@+id/btn1"
 android:text="Item1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
 />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/btn2"
 android:text="Item2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
 />
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btn3"
 android:text="Perform Action"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
 />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/btn4"
 android:text="Ad Goes here"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`. However there are many other layouts which are able to achieve your desired UI. I prefer to just stick to `LinearLayout` because I could just set it to either vertical or horizontal.

Comment: how would I ensure that the ad is docked to the bottom?

Comment: If you need to dock items at bottom for example, then relative layout, like Rahul said, would help. You could use `android:layout_alignParentBottom`. Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Answer (score 2):

You can continue with relative layout in this layout you need to use list-view(simple) and drag button at below of listview. and at the bottom place your advertice sdk area will be stay

[**For more detail....**](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)