# How to set a TextView at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have this layout:

[image: current layout]

It was a bit tricky to put ListView inside ScrollView, but it worked.
When the list is large and the scroll appears when scrolling .. everything up, including the form. That is ok!

Now I would like to put a TextView fixed at the bottom of the screen. As a total

Tried to wrap everything with a RelativeLayout put layout_weight = "1" in ScrollView. Worked. But when the keyboard appears, rises along the TextView and do not want it.

How do I set a TextView at the bottom of the screen, without moving when the keyboard appears?

Comment: I am not pretty sure that I understand your problem. But look at [align views at the bottom of the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen), and make sure about `android:layout_above`. You can also share your xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything in a relative layout. Add the TextView to the relative layout, set layout_alignParentBottom on TextView. Then on the ScrollView set layout_above referencing the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the design hierarchy:

```
<LinearLayout.....>

<ScrollView>

<You Old Views/>

</ScrollView

<TextView> .. </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```