# Position a linearlayout at the bottom of the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, gravity

I would like to have like  a "toolbar" of different widgets at the bottom of my view... Each widget is componed of an `ImageView` that represents the icon and a `TextView` which is the description.
Here is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_shelves"
    android:background="@drawable/final_shelves"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/first_shelf_margin_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:clickable="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image3"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- "Tools" : Cancel, delete, details -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         >

        <!-- Cancel Widget -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/delete_widget"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible">
                <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cancel_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/cancel_128"
                android:clickable="true" />

               <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_above="@id/cancel_icon"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Delete Widget -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_widget"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/delete_blue_128"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delete Card"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/delete_icon"
                android:clickable="true" /> 
         </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Show details Widget -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/show_details_widget"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/show_details_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/info_128"
                android:clickable="true" />

           <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show card details"
                android:layout_below="@id/show_details_icon"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:clickable="true" />

            </RelativeLayout> 

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But my toolbar actually appears just in the bottom of the previous layout. Any idea how to fix the problem ?

Comment: With that layout you have a 3 images, and then under that you have an image and text stacked on top of another image and text stacked on top of another image and text, right?

Comment: @zgc7009 which layout are talking about ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` for your outer layout. When you do, your inner views (in your case: LinearLayout) can have an attribute: 
[layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentBottom)

Actually, your problem is already described here: [How to align views at the bottom of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen?rq=1)

Comment: you mean my root layout should be a relative layout ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use your parent view as `RelativeLayout` then you can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"` to place your layout at the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using this methode, i recommande you to use actionBar like this

[image]

You find all you need in this tutorial
[Working with Action Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

Comment: Actually I would like to have images for a better design, is that possible with the action bar ?

Comment: Yes you can, just choose the icone you want