# Why can't I size android components at will?

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, android

Okay, so I'm really trying to do a lab for a class thing and I don't get why I can't have a textbox that takes up the width of the phone and a button that takes up the width of the phone on the bottom, but I don't know why that is? Here's a picture of what I have.

I know this is a noob question but it hasn't been addressed yet on the online course I'm taking and I really need an answer because I wanted android development to be as easy as .NET on windows.

Well anyway here is one picture:

[image]

Also here is the other picture:
[image]

Notice if I try to make one element bigger, it leads to it pushing the other one out of the activity, I want to have one activity with both elements taking up the entire width of the phone.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 not Mac OS X.

Comment: Not an answer : you should refer Beginning Android 4, as a self-help book to learn about Android.

Comment: That's a really expensive book, that's like what I make a day...lol but thank you I'll check my local library for one of those if it is there.

Comment: No need to buy a book. The android developer site has extensive tutorials and the SDK itself has plenty of example projects.

Comment: `I wanted android development to be as easy as .NET on windows` 2 different platforms, 2 different philosophies.  I really wanted my banana to taste like an orange.  I was disappointed.  As others have said, thinking something will be easy after "I can't be bothered reading documentation and doing all that learning stuff" is a futile exercise.  Start at developer.android.com.

Answer (score 1):

Your controls are children of a LinearLayout with `android:orientation="horizontal"`. This means that the parent ViewGroup is aligning them *horizontally*; you cannot get the children aligned vertically in this configuration.

If you change the attribute to `android:orientation="vertical"`, you will achieve the result you're looking for.

I strongly suggest getting yourself familiar with the default set of layouts available in the Android SDK by reading [this official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Comment: Thank you.
 if I do that they're both placed on the activity close to each other, I want them on opposite sides of the activity, do you know how to do that?

Comment: You can provide an empty View (or Space) in the middle with `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1" `. This effectively consumes the space in between the controls.

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` using a `Relative Layout` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen) for placing views at bottom of the screen.

When you use a `android:orientation=horizontal` orientation in the layout, the views are stacked/placed in a single row. Since both your views have their width set to fill the screen, only the first one is shown/seen.

What you want is the `vertical` orientation. This places the views in a single column, one below the other. The width set to fill-parent will allow you the view to occupy all available space.

- Official documentation on views : [Layouts : Android Dev Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)
- Understanding Android Layouts : [Techtopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Android_Views,_View_Groups_and_Layouts)
- Android Layout Tutorials : [Learn-Android](http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/)