# It's possible to add imageview in a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

I need an information about `Toolbar`. I would like to add four images in my `Toolbar` like home, news, search and message. So i've putting `Imageview`s in the `Toolbar`. Now I don't know how to add listener at these images...how could I do that? 
I have also a navigation drawer and I want that, if you press the `Imageview` in the `Toolbar`, you go in a new `Fragment` and not in a new `Activity`.
So how could I do these two things?
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: What have you done so far? Post some code so we can work it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i guess you know how to add your `imageView`s to your `ToolBar` if not check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063426/best-way-to-create-a-bottom-toolbar-in-android/30063604#30063604) .. After that get a reference to your `ToolBar` use `findViewById`

```
Toolbar tool = finViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);//cast it to ToolBar
ImageView im1 = tool.findViewById(R.id.myimageviewone); // cast it
//same for the others
// now you can set your click listeners
//in your onclick listeners you use fragmentmanager along with fragmenttransaction 
//to start a new fragment in your layout or on your layout, you can google
// for that
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be using the regular `MenuItem` functionality built into the `Toolbar` (and same as ActionBar).  Look up any `ActionBar` tutorial, and look into using ,creating `MenuItems` (you will do most of this in XML).  You will then be able to use the OS framework, to capture `onClickListenter`s.

Here are the docs (you will notice the `MenuItem` has an icon attribute, which will place the images into the `Toolbar`):

> android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"

Docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use `ImageButton`s. You can set image sources which will be displayed as a `Button` and they behave like normal `Button`s with `OnClickListeners`.

Comment: every `View` is clickable sir, they all have normal onclicklisteners