# Add custom layout to toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I followed this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) to give my app a regular toolbar with some tabs.

I want to change the toolbar so it looks more like this:

[image]

I want to add some text and images into the toolbar. How can I do this?

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayout"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: that's a single line toolbar, other information is just linear layouts with the same background color. Also you can add view inside the toolbar just add a closing tag `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

Comment: If I add the layout within the Toolbar tags though, does the behaviour change? What if the Toolbar is 500 pixels tall?

Comment: indirect duplicate of [Best way to create a bottom toolbar in android.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063426/best-way-to-create-a-bottom-toolbar-in-android)

Comment: @Elltz This has absolutely nothing to do with a bottom toolbar. It has to do with modifying the Toolbar provided by Android.

Comment: It acts like a linear layout, it changes the height depending on the views inside the toolbar

Comment: hmm what i was trying to say by that is a Toolbar is a Viewgroup, you can edit it to meet your needs like the one in my soo called "indirect dupe", hope you get it sir?

Comment: you can use toolbar like a viewgroup.

Comment: @user5374735 Have you tried to put layout in between `Toolbar` and `TableLayout`

Answer (score 21):

You can try this :-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <!-   Your view --> 


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:elevation="6dp"
         app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/llContainer"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:background="@android:color/black"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_height="300dp">

                 <!-  Your TextView / ImageView -->

            </LinearLayout>

      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:id="@+id/tabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayout"
          app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define ToolBar custom layout using constraint layout as shown below, see http://www.zoftino.com/android-toolbar-tutorial for more information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="zoftino.com.toolbar.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_m"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Tennis"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/women_s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="W Singles"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_m" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wm_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
                android:text="Serena"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/women_s"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_m" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Android ActionBar is now easier to customise than ever, due to the fact that the old ActionBar element has been replaced with the more versitile Toolbar. for more [detail reference link 1](http://sourcey.com/android-custom-centered-actionbar-with-material-design/) and [detail reference link 2](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html)

Comment: This is an example of where the answer should display the important stuff from the links, in case links stops working.