# ActionBar menu with text ,icon,text

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

Hello guys i want to display action with text and images on action bar, but i only get text in overflow menu

my menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_show_ir_list"

    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Cancel"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:title="Wowio"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
  />
  <!--android:icon="@drawable/info"-->

  <item
    android:id="@+id/computer"
    android:title="Done"

    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />


    </menu>
```

in my main class

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.phone:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected About App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.computer:


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected About Developer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.action_show_ir_list:

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Volume Set To Max", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
    return true;

}
```

Here every thing is coming in over flow menu nothing is coming on action bar
[image]

I tried every thing on internet and nothing is working

What should i do to show them on ActionBar?

Comment: Use custom view in toolbar check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774757/add-custom-layout-to-toolbar)

Comment: i Dont want to use Tool bar ,it is supporting in sample projects but when we integrate with mainproject it give errors

Comment: Then check this http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:[yourapp]="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_add_size"
android:title="@string/menu_add_item"
android:orderInCategory="10"
[yourapp]:showAsAction="always"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

instead of [yourapp] type your app name

Comment: tried all options there but nothing is working   ifroom, withtext , always ,never

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored

Comment: @Redman, try to use custom toolbar, if nothing works for you. but above solution should work

Comment: edit Your answer and copy paste my answer and i will accept it