# Toolbar does not appear android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to play around with some Android code for the first time. I have been following at the beginning the Hello World example until when you create a text input and then launch a different Activity and send the text input content activity by pressing the send button.

Now I want to add a bottom ToolBar for navigation so I implement an empty activity that is separate to define the toolbar and that I then  in my main activity. But as you can see no toolbar actually appears however my text input itself has disappeared and my send button now appears somewhere else... I don't really know what I am doing to be honest so if I could get some explanation I would highly appreciate it:

UPDATE: I have tried the solution from @prat see the new screenshots attached.

UPDATE 2: solved by setting the relativelayout to vertical instead of horizontal.

[image]

[image]

Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is a bar that resembles the updated navbar at the bottom from Google's Material Design guidelines:

[image]

Comment: You've set the orientation to horizontal. And are you setting it as toolbar in `MyActivity.java`?

Comment: I see nowhere where it says it's horizontal, and isn't that the point of a horizontal navigation bar? Also why MyActivity.java?

Comment: Your LinearLayout is set to horizontal. That's why it is at the right and not the bottom. Here is an example for the toolbar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30063604/4583267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bottom toolbar.try this code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello_android" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've updated the post above using the solution from @prat, doesn't seem to do the trick, do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @FlorianMonfort try this github link https://github.com/DevLight-Mobile-Agency/NavigationTabBar

Comment: I'd rather not use a pre-built framework but learn how to do this myself, even if it's not as good

Comment: Figured it out! I looked at the differences and so it was not in the ToolBar XML part but the Relative Layout that it had to be set to vertical and not horizontal. Was not looking at the right code block. I think that's what you meant @Exception Lover

Comment: Yes sorry like I said, I didn't look at the right code block and did not see where your comment applied... my  bad

Answer (score 1):

For toolbar at the bottom,try like this

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primaryBlue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ahotbrew.toolbar.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="hello_brew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am trying your solution but I seem to have a problem with the color attribute: the line is in red and AS indicates "Cannot resolve symbol @color/primaryBlue" ...?

Comment: For color , u have to mention the color in color.xml file. U can mention ur own color and can call from xml

Comment: Arf I can't show the result here, but it doesn't really do what I am expecting...

Comment: I've updated the post above with the new result based on your code, doesn't seem to do the trick so far

Comment: Remove  relative layout in second xml having tool bar. I have checked the same code ..fr me it's working fine

Comment: Still not working. Is there a service a can use to upload new images?

Comment: Pls post the screenshot for ur desired   latout

Comment: How do I post it, in the main post, I just update it?