# Align LinearLayout at the bottom

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

I want to align a `LinearLayout` at the bottom. I read many posts of the same problem and I still don't make it. [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)  there is a similiar problem. But the answer didn't help me.

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_fondo">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/indicador_wizzard2"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Días de ingesta"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:weightSum="49">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/lunes"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                android:textOn="Lu"
                android:textOff="Lu"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/martes"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                android:textOn="Ma"
                android:textOff="Ma"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/miercoles"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                android:textOn="Mie"
                android:textOff="Mie"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/jueves"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                android:textOn="Jue"
                android:textOff="Jue"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/viernes"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                android:textOn="Vie"
                android:textOff="Vie"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/sabado"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                android:textOn="Sa"
                android:textOff="Sa"/>
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/domingo"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                android:textOn="Do"
                android:textOff="Do"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Hora"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Dosis"/>



        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                style="@style/botones"
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancelar2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Atrás"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button
                style="@style/botones"
                android:id="@+id/btn_irapaso3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Continuar"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Help me please I'm going crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change the topmost `LinearLayout` to have `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Then, wrap the 3 layouts above the one you want at the bottom in a parent `LinearLayout`, with `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

Here is the full layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_fondo"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/indicador_wizzard2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Días de ingesta"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="Hora"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:text="Dosis"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:weightSum="49">

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/lunes"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                        android:textOn="Lu"
                        android:textOff="Lu"/>
                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/martes"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                        android:textOn="Ma"
                        android:textOff="Ma"/>
                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/miercoles"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                        android:textOn="Mie"
                        android:textOff="Mie"/>
                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/jueves"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                        android:textOn="Jue"
                        android:textOff="Jue"/>
                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/viernes"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                        android:textOn="Vie"
                        android:textOff="Vie"/>
                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/sabado"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                        android:textOn="Sa"
                        android:textOff="Sa"/>
                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/domingo"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/botonesdias"
                        android:textOn="Do"
                        android:textOff="Do"/>


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    style="@style/botones"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cancelar2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Atrás"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <Button
                    style="@style/botones"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_irapaso3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Continuar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I can't mark the answer as useful because my reputation! A lot of thanks again for help me.