# White line at the bottom of the screen (LinearLayout)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am working on a login screen for my app. The issue is I am getting a white line at the bottom of the screen on every device and on the emulator as well.
You can check the output here: 
http://www.imgur.com/cTMu4Ap
This is my xml code for the layout. Please note that I am using layout_weight property for equal space among all devices.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="55dp"
        android:paddingRight="55dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtEmailOrMobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_or_mobile_number"
            android:background="@null"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clear"

            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:background="@null"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clear"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clear"

            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_login_button"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button_login_background"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dont_have_an_account"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_create_account_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create_an_account"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It could be in @drawable/button_create_account_background . Also, try adding android:weightSum="1.7" to your main LinearLayout.

Comment: You can try put the `backgroundColor`on you first (and principal) `LinearLayout` to the same color `Create Account Button`

Comment: @Aspicas: yes its working, thanks. But I want to know the reason of this white line please. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try adding android:padding = "0dp" to your last linear layout

Comment: @user2787602 It's because the elements on screen don't fill a full screen, maybe you have some `weight` with a bad number, but really.... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Where is fault**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_create_account_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_an_account"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Actually Your last layout is not `purely` bottom side .Thats why have problem .Another problem`android:layout_weight="0.2"` .The **android:layout_weight** is not proper for set bottom side .

**Try this**

I think you should try a relative layout.If you have a relative layout that fills the whole screen you should be able to use [android:layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3Alayout_alignParentBottom) to move the button to the bottom of the screen. [Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

**Or**

You can use [LinearLayout android:weightSum](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) Property .

> [What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: yes I can do that but I want the layout_weight property which is not available in RelativeLayout. Thanks.

Comment: @user2787602 Another reason .Actually when use set ` android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` thats why have problem .Avoid Hard coded value .You can use `android:weightSum` Property

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I have found of fixing the 1dp line issue is to scale up the values you are using for the weights.

An easy way to do this is to scale each weight until there are no decimal points, so for example:

```
android:layout_weight="0.2"
```

would become

```
android:layout_weight"2"
```

Provided you apply this multiplier to each weight in your layout they should all maintain the same scale but with no line at the bottom.

I can't say for certain, but my assumption is that using smaller decimal values results in some rounding error by Android - leaving the unwanted 1dp line at the bottom of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changing `android:layout_height="match_parent"` of LinearLayout to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` solved the problem.

The white border was showing only on one "slide" in my application. I am not sure, but I think the image that we display can have influence on that.

Of course, changing layout_height is not what we can always do. It's rather like a work-around, not a proper solution.