# Arranging elements in xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout

I used

```
drawerlayout
```

in my xml.  I can able to align properly in Relative layout but I am **struggling** with this drawer layout.

Cant use most of the feature which i used in Relative layout.

But i somewhat managed to align elements in the places where i want . But it gave me another problem.

• In Android Studio's **XML Preview** it was **perfectly aligned** ,

• In **Emulator (while Compiling)** I **can't see the elements**  Textview and Button.

• When i installed in **my Mobile** , these elements were **little above** from the bottom.

---

You can see three pictures below ,

[image: XML Preview] [image: Emulator (Nexus One)]
[image: My own mobile (Micromax)]

---

Q1. So **why** these different types of alignment i am getting .

Q2. How can i code so that **UI** should look **same in all the devices**

Q3. What **mistake** i did in my **XML Code** (Posted Below) and what is the replacement code to get same UI in all devices.

XML Code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dbListrv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="505dp"
            />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="505dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I also request you to say some tips to arrange elements flexibily.
Thanks in advance. (:

Comment: You should really reconsider your design because giving fixed height to `RecyclerView` is not a nice thing.

Comment: It it might be why you are facing the problem. Try by changing height of `RecyclerView` to, say, 100dp.

Comment: I want my recycler list tat much height...  i cant reduce it.  I want it in whole page nd leaving small space below for text view nd button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for my question. Using a fixed height for the elements may look perfect in your xml . But they will differ among different mobiles which have different **screen size**.

Hence providing **fixed height is not a good idea.**

So, Use **LinearLayout** (Nested LinearLayout if needed) and set **Weight** of each elements.

Set orientation as **Horizontal** if you want to align your elements as **Columns**.

Set orientation as **Vertical** if you want to align your elements as **Rows**.

Weight will matter how much space an element should occupy in the defined layout.

Here is my code without using fixed heights,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/FirstRL"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dbListrv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="10">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_weight="5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Finally i found solution for my own question. Hope it will help others too..

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is because you are using a fixed height for your RecyclerView.

It takes up more space on some screens than it does on others giving the effect you are seeing.

Try putting your RecyclerView inside a RelativeLayout and set its height to MATCH_PARENT.

Also use the RelativeLayout to align your button and textview to the bottom of the screen which is what I think you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You mean,  two relative layouts??  one for recycler view and another for TV and button?

Comment: If you have time, can you correct my code and paste it as answer here..?

Comment: I dont have time right now but have a look at this which should help you along. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Comment: They used Relative layout whereas I used Drawer Layout.....  There i can use many functions such as " android:layout_alignParentTop"  and layout_leftOf sumting lik tat.....  but in Drawer Layout I can't able to use any of these...  that's why I asked this question....  Hope u understand and u give me solution once u get time...