# Why only one attribute in layout_gravity in my xml working

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want my reset button to be at bottom and horizontally centered, but `layout_gravity` is not working, only one of them is working.

I know it can be done by choosing `RelativeLayout` as my parent layout but I want to do it with `LinearLayout` as my parent layout.

I just want reset button as bottom and horizontally centered rest everything is fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="TEAM A" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="button3"
            android:text="+3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="button2"
            android:text="+2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="button1"
            android:text="Free Throw" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="TEAM B" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="button3_b"
            android:text="+3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="button2_b"
            android:text="+2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="button1_b"
            android:text="Free Throw" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="resetButton"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="RESET" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead if you don't want to go completely relative (inside the parent Linear Layout):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:onClick="resetButton"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

or if you don't want to keep the reset button inside a relative layout, there doesn't seem to be a solution.

You can check this out as well: [How to align views at the bottom of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Since the rest of your ViewGroups in that layout fill the parent's width, you could simply set the parent LinearLayout's gravity to center_horizontal and it should line up properly, without affecting the other children:

```
<LinearLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity">
```

Edit: I didn't notice you also wanted it at the bottom... This can be achieved with an invisible weighted View between your content and the bottom:

```
    ...

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="resetButton"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="RESET" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 2: Removed layout_gravity on your button since it no longer applies.