# Unable to force images to be at bottom

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#EDEDED">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#db4437"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHeader"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
           android:src="@drawable/cruise"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            />
        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/textbox"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/user_male"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_male"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="10dp"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:hint="Email..." />
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/textbox"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/user_male"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_male"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="20dp"
            android:maxWidth="20dp"
            android:hint="Password..." />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#EDEDED"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >

            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:text="Forgot password?"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#EDEDED"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#db4437"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@id/bottom"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"

            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/vai_one"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/vai_twi" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/vai_three" />

        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Im using the following code The last linear layout contains three images and I want those images to be at the bottom of the screen but it is not being fixed at the bottom. How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: Gravity doesn't do what you think it does. Try to use a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible dublicate of [How to align views at the bottom of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen?rq=1)

try using `RelativeLayout`. Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EDEDED"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4"
        tools:context="com.MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#db4437"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgHeader"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/cruise" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Header"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <EditText
                style="@style/textbox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_male"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/user_male"
                android:hint="Email..."
                android:maxHeight="10dp"
                android:maxWidth="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/textbox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_male"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/user_male"
                android:hint="Password..."
                android:maxHeight="20dp"
                android:maxWidth="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="#EDEDED"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="Forgot password?"
                    android:textColor="#CCCCCC" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#db4437"
                    android:text="Login" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/vai_one" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/vai_twi" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/vai_three" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` is key paramater.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

try using a `RelativeLayout` instead to fill the whole screen and

the `android:layout_alignParentBottom`  attribute