# Android - Dock Textview and button on bottom of page

Tags: android

I have no idea how to put part of my textview and buttons on the bottom of the page. I tried to gravity bottom, etc.. but it didnt work.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.HomeFragment"
android:background="@color/AMOB_gray">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Company"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/welcomeAmobHome"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Follow us on our Social Networks"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_twitter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/twitter_icon"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_youtube"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/instagram_icon"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_instagram"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/youtube_icon"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_flickr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:background="@drawable/flikr_icon"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I only want to dock the buttons and the textview that says "Follow us on our Social Networks".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XURwP.png)

Comment: please try with RelativeLayout

Comment: @AvishekDas agree . Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help you,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.HomeFragment"
android:background="@color/AMOB_gray">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Company"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/welcomeAmobHome"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView10"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Follow us on our Social Networks"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView11"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView12"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_twitter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/twitter_icon"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_youtube"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/instagram_icon"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_instagram"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/youtube_icon"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_flickr"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/flikr_icon"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```