# Adding AdView to Linear layout below another shows nothing

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-linearlayout

I add a View to my linearlayout this way:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

mGameView = new GameView(this);

mLinearLayout.addView(mGameView);
```

This layout shows no `AdView`. I expected it to show the `AdView` below my other view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-xx"
            >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout file shows the AdView but it shows it at the top. I want to show it at the bottom

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-XX"
            >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root Layout is `RelativeLayout`,So You want show the `AdView` at bottom of Layout .You can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your `linearLayout2` .

Try this .

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-XX">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/46773612#46773612) answer I had answered .

**Edit**

You can try use `LinearLayout` as root layout .And set `android:layout_weight="1"` for first `LinearlLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-XX">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can remove first `linearLayout` and try

Comment: I tried, this shows AdView on top of GameView. I want AdView at bottom, last view in linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-XX"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent relative layout to Linear layout. have look:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-XX">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

it works in my code.
Happy coding!!

Comment: The Adview is invisible in this format - the GameView takes up the entire screen. I want the AdView to show at bottom of the layout.