# Pin a view to bottom of screen in BottomSheetDialog Fragment

Tags: android, modal-dialog, bottom-sheet

I've used BottomSheetDialogFragment in my project and I've designed it as below:

[image: BottomSheetDialogFragment]

***Target:*** I'm going to stick the bottom menu of BottomSheetDialog to bottom of the screen, in either mode collapse and expand.

So in BottomSheetDialog layout, I used RelativeLayout for parent and "layout_alignParentBottom" for menu container, As below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
tools:context=".MyBottomSheetDialogFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topSection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    ....
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/topSection">
    ....
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/iconsContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    ....
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the dialogue is as follows:

[image: BottomSheetDialog]

As you can see, the bottom menu is not visible at first.

*Can someone help me to solve this problem?*

Comment: How about seting `gravity` to `bottom`? haven't you tried that yet? Also, as i can see, you have few views under eachother with a `RelativeLayout` which could be a `LinearLayout`-`FrameLayout` at the top of the layout which you could manage other below layouts easily. You may wanna look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099076/4409113

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท I did it, but in fact the problem is, I'm going to do this in BottomSheetDialog!
If you look at this picture, you will find out what the reason for this is:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=5392871352&photo_id=500985077017

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this, several things came to my mind when I tried, but I did not succeed.

**But this finally solved for me by this way:**

For collapse mode, I set the bottomSheetBehavior's peekHeight to 1/3 of the screen (with the following code):

```
    View bottomSheetContainer = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer);
    View parent = (View) bottomSheetContainer.getParent();
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) params.getBehavior();
    View inflatedView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.word_details_bottom_sheet, null);
    inflatedView.measure(0, 0);
    int screenHeight = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    if (bottomSheetBehavior != null) {
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(screenHeight /3);
    }
```

**So I decided to do it:**

*1- for collapse mode: bottomSheet container's height = bottomSheetBehavior's peekHeight*

*2- for expand mode: bottomSheet container's height = full screen Height*

So I wrote the following code (full code):

*WordDetailsBottomSheet.java*

```
public class WordDetailsBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

public WordDetailsBottomSheet() { // Required empty public constructor }

@NotNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity(), 0);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.word_details_bottom_sheet);

    View bottomSheetContainer = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer);
    View parent = (View) bottomSheetContainer.getParent();
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) params.getBehavior();
    View inflatedView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.word_details_bottom_sheet, null);
    inflatedView.measure(0, 0);
    int screenHeight = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();

    if (bottomSheetBehavior != null) {
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(screenHeight / BOTTOM_SHEET_PEEK_HEIGHT_PERCENT);
        bottomSheetContainer.getLayoutParams().height = bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight();
    }

    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View view, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                    bottomSheetContainer.getLayoutParams().height = screenHeight-statusBarHeight;
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                    bottomSheetContainer.getLayoutParams().height = bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight();
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    dismiss();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}

public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
    }
}
```

*word_details_bottom_sheet.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
tools:context=".MyBottomSheetDialogFragment">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/topSection"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
....
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/descriptionContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/topSection">
....
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/iconsContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
....
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the xml file, things that matter are:

*1- parent id (android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer")*

*2- iconsContainer align (android:layout_alignParentBottom="true")*

[image]

Comment: That's more like **a custom** `BottomSheetDialogFragment` than a problem with `BottomSheetDialog` which i have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, the bottom menu is not visible at first.
>
> Can someone help me to ***solve this problem***?

I'm guessing that this behavior ***is working perfectly and fine***  because you set `layout_height` of `NestedScrollView` *(Center content)* to `wrap_content` which means, it will be wrapped **by the content inside**.

Meanwhile;

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

To `HorizontalScrollView` *(below `layout`)* means that it will be under the other `layout`s **which it currently is!**

So, *if you are trying to see if it is working fine or not*, set `100dp`-`50dp` (or a specific size which you can see when `BottomSheetDialog` show up) instead of `wrap_content` to `NestedScrollView` then you probably would see that the below `layout` with the other `layout`s will be visible.

Anyways, everything's in this layout looks correct and fine. As well as pictures says the truth.