# How to arrange icons from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout

I am working on a launcher application in which I want to set the app icons from the bottom of the screen first and then fill upwards. This is important as I want to keep the icons close to the navigation bars.
I tried using the LinearLayoutManager and Gravity as well but none of them seems to resolve my issue.

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    appIcons.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    appIcons.setLayoutParams(layout.getLayoutParams());
```

Comment: Is there more to that code sample? You've created a `LinearLayout` but never shown any code using it.

Comment: @HenryTwist Sorry missed this while copying. Updated the code.

Comment: Is there are reason you're doing this programmatically? And what layout is your RecyclerView wrapped in?

Answer (score 0):

Gravity will change only elements inside Liner-Layout. So if the liner-Layout if not match the parent in Hight it won't affect it. This might help you too.

[How do I align views at the bottom of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386866/11573842)